# Fine tune in using Huggingface

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, fine-tuning

I am totally new bee in NLP and I want to fine tune a pre-trained model (rebel-large) with my onw dataset. After reading some tutorials I frealized there is no difference between training and fine tuning? I mean I understand they are not the same, but in the code there are no difference.

How can I define how I want to fine tune the model? E.g. if I just want to change the weights in the last layer, how should I make the trained to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, fine-tuning a model is the same as loading a pre-trained model and then training it.
You can use the following snippet, and replace the dataset with yours.

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer
import numpy as np
import evaluate

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
metric = evaluate.load('accuracy')


def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples['text'], padding='max_length', truncation=True)


def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)


dataset = load_dataset('imdb')
dataset = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

# print(model)  # Use to discover your layers and choose which ones to put in `to_freeze`

to_freeze = [model.bert.encoder]

for layer in to_freeze:
    for param in layer.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False

training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir='test_trainer')
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset['train'],
    eval_dataset=dataset['test']
)
trainer.train()
```